# Simple game conversion to Silverlight, what to render on?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have had a small game (Written in C#) which I've built up over time (started in vb6/bitblt) which I would like to convert to Silverlight, essentially to give me a good interesting project to learn the platform.

My question is simple, (the game is a tile based game) I need to render somthing. How is this performed in Silverlight, as things stand I have a number of sprite and tile sheets and we Blt each tile to the surface (Picturebox)

Is the concept the same in silverlight, do we need to use a Picturebox as the surface? What are the rendering functions? External Libs? I'm seen the WritableBmp function, Could somone point me in the right direction to get us started?

==========================

Thanks for the replies, some more info about the game.

Its a single player, tile based RPG. I would need to render tiles, and then characters and objects onto the tiles (Or multiple tiles) with that in mind, what would be the optimum way to achieve this? Performance is key, everyone hates flickering, jittery games.

With that said, is anyone aware of any samples that simulate what we have spoken about?

Comment: It sounds like your game is reasonably simple. Maybe you should just use an object for each tile and store these tiles in a uniform(?) grid? then Silverlight would do the rendering :)

Comment: Comment: Of course I don't know your requirements, but FYI, a PictureBox is *not* usually a good surface to render on. I'd much rather create my own control derived from Control and provide custom painting. This will probably also speed up your game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). It was designed just for situations like this.

For an example on how to use it you could look at my simple sprite-based-game-library, [SilverTile](http://silvertile.codeplex.com/). Is uses the WriteableBitmap as its rendering surface and performs reasonably well.

If you want to write everything from scratch you should look at the [WriteableBitmapExtensions](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) project. It gives you extension methods that simplifies working with the WriteableBitmap.

Edit:  Oh, and this reminded me that I need to update the code on Codeplex. Contact me if you want a more recent version of the code along with some samples.

Comment: @Rune Grimstad I'm going to download and have a look, I've added a little more info to main post!

Comment: @Pino: From your description it sounds like you can use the principles from my game engine. I am working on a Silverlight Zelda remake now: http://blog.rag.no/post/New-version-of-the-sample-application-is-ready.aspx

Comment: Looks very impressive! Infact the sudo 3d one does as well. Kinda reminds me of - http://www.noteme.com/doomsharp/

Comment: Do you have the source for the Zelda port?

Comment: @Pino: Yep. I wrote it after all. But it is a mess :-) You can find my contact information on my blog: http://blog.rag.no. Send me an email and I will send you a copy of the latest code.

Comment: Also, you should look at Balder 3D: http://balder.codeplex.com/ It is a really nice 3d-engine for Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

If you need control over every pixel on screen, you can do **WriteableBitmap**. You'd create a Grid with a single row and single cell, add an Image element to that cell, and set the Image.Source to your WriteableBitmap.

If you don't need control over every pixel, but need to position things (images, text, etc.) using absolute coordinates, use **Canvas**.

If you don't need control over absolute coordinates, and just want the UI to layout tiles in rows and columns, use **Grid** or **UniformGrid**, with a tile in each cell.

One thing to keep in mind since your'e starting out new to Silverlight, know that rendering in Silverlight (and WPF) is very different than VB6, Win32, and WinForms world.

In the old world, to draw stuff, you'd override some Paint method, then call an API to draw it at X,Y.

By contrast, in the new world, you declaratively say, "Use this container to display this data". Very different model, different way of thinking.

---

**Edit** Ok, after seeing your update, I recommend you use Canvas. You can position anything in a canvas using {X, Y} coordinates. I think this will work nicely for a tile-based 2d game. For examples, search Silverlight tile game, for instance, [Silverlight Tile Engine](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/160582.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, most useful! I've updated the main post with a little more info.